# Docker desktop eats all memory and crashes

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Using Docker Desktop (19.03.13) with 6 containers in Windows 10. Having 16GB RAM.

In `docker stats` each container consumes 20-500 mb, all together cunsume ~1gb.

But in the Task Manager docker eats ~10gb and crashes from the lack of system memory.

How to check, what consumes so much memory in docker?
And how to prevent this?

Comment: what is your windows version ? (i mean the build)? also check this link https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/

Comment: Windows Version 1703 (OS Build 15063.2108)

Comment: By default, any Docker Container may consume as much of the hardware such as CPU and RAM. If you are running multiple containers on the same host you should limit how much memory they can consume.

Comment: I limited all containers to 1Gb in Settings - Resources. Not helped.

Comment: `Settings - Resources` limits resources of whole Docker machine where containers are running. So you made it even worse, because all containers together consume ~1GB and your Docker machine has 1GB limit as well. @Ashok pointed his comment to the container limitation - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources

Comment: In Hyper-V Isolation mode (default) Windows is reserves memory of each container  so if when you set 1 GB limit then 10 containers should need ~10GB of RAM.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/hyperv-container
If you use Linux based images then you should use docker together with WSL2 (Windows build 2004)

Comment: I have only 6 containers. Also in "docker stats" each container consumes 20-500 mb. So it can't be 10GB of RAM.

Comment: Did you remove all your old stopped containers? Check `docker ps -a`. If there are more then your six running containers run `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` to remove all present containers (currently running included). If the problem persist try deleting all unused networks by running `docker network prune`. 
I don't think it's something Windows specific as I sometimes experience the same issue in OSX – from my experience it's related to not stopping containers properly. Maybe it'll help :)

Answer (score 46):

Try to create a `.wslconfig` file at the root of your User folder `C:\Users\<my-user>` to adjust how much memory & processors Docker will use.

This is the content of the `.wslconfig` file.

```
[wsl2]
memory=2GB   # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 up to 2GB
processors=2# Makes the WSL 2 VM use two virtual processors
```

Then, restart the computer. You will find the `Vemm` process will only take the amount of RAM you defined previously.

You can learn more here [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#example-wslconfig-file)

Comment: you dont even have to restart computer, this worked for me!

Answer (score 11):

I guess you are using the new WSL 2 based engine, try **switching docker engine back to Hyper-V** by going opening `docker settings` -> `general` -> uncheck `Use WSL 2 based Engine` .

**To explain:**

I noticed it started happening to me since WSL 2 engine was introduced, i automatically switched to it since it's a new engine; Memory issues started arising since then.

Restarting/closing docker did not free the memory and i noticed in task Manager `Vemm` was the one eating all memory, so had to force close it (caused docker not to work).

Last thing i did was **switching docker engine back to Hyper-V** solved my high memory usage.

Comment: May 2023, 16GB Win10 with SSD, DD v4.18: 6GB on WSL2 engine, and disk thrashing, unusable. Using Hyper-V engine: responsive, 0.2GB.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using WSL2 put into the .wslconfig the middle of your ram. I don't know why but I had the same problem with 8GB RAM.

This is my **.wslconfig**

```
[wsl2]
memory=4GB # I have 8GB RAM
processors=2
```

And the result was good because the consumption is good! In this moment I have running a Docker with 8 images:

[image: The result was the following]

Comment: Docker Desktop (v4.18)  shows I am configured to use 2GB of RAM -- but using WSL2 engine, Virtual Environment is using 6GB (no open containers).

Answer (score 5):

Although this problem is already marked as SOLVED

There is still another reason for this, in recently updated versions.

You might enable too many resources for docker hyperkit.

Go to settings - resources - advanced
check if you spared too much resource there.
[image]

Comment: For context, WSL2 does not support this method of resource control and needs to be configured in a `.wslconfig` file as mentioned in many answers here.

This screenshot looks like an OSX example

Comment: @muspimerol you are right, this is an osx option.

Answer (score 5):

I have my docker taking less than 2% cpu now.

After updating .wslconfig to be:

```
[wsl2]
memory=8GB
swap=2000
processors=4
```

... and then restarting Docker, the CPU consumption was still over 80% and there were 5 Docker Desktop processes (each taking 17-18%) in Windows Task Manager. I reset Docket to Factory and still the CPU pegged at 80% or more.

I then deleted the .docker folder (in windows the path is %USERPROFILE%/.docker) as suggested by jmichalek-fp. I took care to do a Shift-DEL so as not to move it to the recylce bin because I remember in the past recycled items were still found by processes that hold a link to the file.

After Factory Reset, then increasing .wslconfig resources, then deleting .docker folder and then restarting Docker, it is now running only one Docker Desktop process, and, with a NodeJs app running in it, it is consuming between 0.5% and 2% CPU.

I found "delete .docker folder" in this github issue: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12266

Comment: Added .wslconfig ... restarted wsl using command "wsl --shutdown" in cmd(admin). This worked for me. Did not have to delete .docker folder.

Answer (score 2):

These are the settings I use on my old computer.

```
[wsl2]
memory=2GB   # Limits VM memory in WSL 2 up to 2GB
processors=2# Makes the WSL 2 VM use two virtual processors
guiApplications=false #you won't use it with docker desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know docker stats does not show RAM reservations. Try to put RAM limits using -m flag. There are some information how to control resources using docker:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/?spm=a2c41.12663380.0.0.59ed566dAqUZPu

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, you need to check if the file is named ".wslconfig.txt" and remove the ".txt" extension if it exists. Renaming the file to ".wslconfig" will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using the command `sudo docker stats` and can see the memory allocation for the docker. As per my understanding, your docker is taking memory more than expected.

Solution:
It would be best if you allocated less memory, I updated my `docker-compose.yaml` file and added below line to allocate and reserve the memory for docker as:

```
  deploy:
   resources:
    limits:
     memory: 512M
    reservations:
     memory: 300M
```

After adding the above line your docker will take up to 512MB.

[image]

**Here are sample `docker-compose.yaml` file**

```
version: '3' # Use version 3 or higher

services: # Use 'services' (plural) to define your services
 backend:
  container_name: track_easy_server_container
  image: track_easy_server_image
  deploy:
   resources:
    limits:
     memory: 512M
    reservations:
     memory: 300M
  build:
   context: .
   target: production
   dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  command: npm run start:prod
  environment:
   - APP_ENV=PROD
  env_file: .env
  ports:
   - '3010:3010'
  volumes:
   - .:/user/src/app
   - /usr/src/app/node_modules
  restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score -6):

I am guessing on Windows there is something similar to what exists on MacOS.

1. Open your docker app and go to the dashboard
2. Click any container
3. Click `Stats`

You will get information regarding your CPU, RAM Usage, Disk Read & Write Memory & Network usage.

[image]

When I had memory issues, which I used to frequently, I would setup alias scripts that I could chain together to stop/kill/restart and do what ever setup I needed on the containers.

There is no preventing docker behaving the way it behaves unless you want to start contributing to and making pull requests. This isn't an uncommon issue. Docker is a free service, I recommend working around it's short comings.